# How to have iframe resize after clicking a link inside of the iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, iframe-resizer

I'm using iFrame Resizer to embed a cross domain iframe on a page. This works well, until I click on a link inside of the iframe that takes me to the next page.

In the iframe source page (the remote one) I've got the following code in the header:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/iframe-resizer@3.6.1/js/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js"></script>
```

In the page that's embedding the iframe I've got:

```
<iframe id="crelate-iframe" src="https://foo.bar" frameborder="0" width="100%" scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

and in the footer of the page:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/iframe-resizer@3.6.1/js/iframeResizer.min.js?ver=1'></script>

<script>
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('#crelate-iframe').iFrameResize({
            log: true,
            heightCalculationMethod: 'lowestElement'
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

The logging doesn't give away much as far as I can tell. I can only see it initially adjusts the height of the iframe, but when I click through it doesn't and when the next page's height is smaller then I end up with a bunch of white-space at the bottom.

Any ideas what could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Each page that you load into the iFrame needs script added to it

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/iframe-resizer@3.6.1/js/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js"></script>
```